# C# Accessing controls from an outside class without "public"

Tags: c#

I know this has been asked before but I believe my situation is a bit different -- or I don't understand the answers given.  I have spent about 4 hours working on this solidly and finally realized, I just don't know what to do.

I have 2 Forms (Form1, Settings) and a class I created called Themes.

I have get/set properties that currently work but are all within Form1 and I would like to move as much code related to themeing as I can OUTSIDE of Form1 and into `Themes.cs`.

Changing Theme:  To change the theme, the user opens up the Settings form and selects a theme from the dropdown menu and presses the 'Set' button -- this all works, but now I want to move it into my own class and I can't get the code to compile.

Here is example code that works before moving -- note that this is only 2 different controls I want to modify but there are about 30 total.  I am abridging the code:

Form 1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings frm = new Settings(this);
        frm.Show();
    }

    private Color txtRSSURLBGProperty;
    private Color txtRSSURLFGProperty;

    public Color TxtRSSURLBGProperty
    {
        get { return txtRSSURLBGProperty; }
        set { txtRSSURL.BackColor = value; }
    }

    public Color TxtRSSURLFGProperty
    {
        get { return txtRSSURLFGProperty; }
        set { txtRSSURL.ForeColor = value; }
    }
```

Settings Form:

```
public partial class Settings : Form
{
    public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 rssReaderMain = null;

    public Settings(Form requestingForm)
    {
        rssReaderMain = requestingForm as Form1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Appearence settings for DEFAULT THEME

        if (cbThemeSelect.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            this.rssReaderMain.TxtRSSURLBGProperty = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
            this.rssReaderMain.TxtRSSURLFGProperty = Color.White;
            [......about 25 more of these....]
        }
```

The theme class is currently empty.  Again, the goal is to move as much code into the themes class (specifically the get/set statements if at all possible!) and hopefully just use a method similar to this within the Settings form once the proper drowndown item is selected: `SetTheme(Default);`

I hope someone can help, and I hope I explained it right! I have been racking my brain and I need to have this done fairly soon!  Much thanks in advance as I'm sure everyone says.  I have teamviewer or logmein if someone wants to remote in -- that is just as easy.

I can also send my project as a zip if needed.

Thanks so much,

Kurt

Modified code for review:

Form1 form:

```
public partial class Form1 : ThemeableForm
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

ThemeableForm form:

```
internal abstract class ThemeableForm : Form
{
    private Color rssLabelBGProperty;
    private Color rssLabelFGProperty;

    public Color RssLabelBGProperty
    {
        get { return rssLabelBGProperty; }
        set { lRSS.BackColor = value; }
    }

    public Color RssLabelFGProperty
    {
        get { return rssLabelFGProperty; }
        set { lRSS.ForeColor = value; }
    }
```

Settings form:

```
    public Settings(ThemeableForm requestingForm)
    {
        rssReaderMain = requestingForm as ThemeableForm;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ThemeableForm rssReaderMain = null;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        // Appearence settings for DEFAULT THEME

        if (cbThemeSelect.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            this.rssReaderMain.LRSSBGProperty = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
            this.rssReaderMain.LRSSFGProperty = Color.White;
        }
```

Now the all the controls in my get/set (lRSS in the example code above) error out with `does not exist in the current context`.  I also get the warning:

> Warning   1The designer could not be shown for this file because none of
>   the classes within it can be designed.  The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file:
>
> Form1 --- The base class 'RSSReader_BKRF.ThemeableForm' could not be
>   loaded.  Ensure the assembly has been referenced and that all projects
>   have been built.      0   0

Comment: Seems like Winforms, from his code snippets.  Webforms inherit from Page.

Comment: Sorry didnt ever answer this nor see it -- its C# Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

Let the `Themes` class be composed largely of data that changes when a theme changes: Color, Fonts, etc.

Let the Settings form choose a theme and write it out as the Default Theme. If this is WinForms, then you can just have a static `CurrentTheme` property of the Themes class which returns the theme chosen on the Settings form.

Let the Form1 and any other forms delegate some of their properties to the current theme:

```
private Color BackgroundColor
{
    get {return Themes.CurrentTheme.BackgroundColor;}
}

private Color TextColor
{
    get {return Themes.CurrentTheme.TextColor;}
}
```

You might then want to push these delegated properties up to a base form class, to be shared by multiple forms.

Comment: Hey John, Thank you for your quick reply as well.  Do you think you could use the code I provided to show me example of what you are suggesting.  I didn't follow some of that and would love a code example!

Comment: @Kurt: sorry, I won't have time to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see you are trying to make the Settings form manipulate the values of properties on several (many?) other forms.

One solution is to have every other form inherit from the same abstract class, let's call it ThemeableForm.  Now you can define ThemeableForm to have all the common properties.

A short example:

```
internal abstract class ThemeableForm : Form {
    private Color txtRSSURLBGProperty;
    private Color txtRSSURLFGProperty;

    public Color TxtRSSURLBGProperty
    {
        get { return txtRSSURLBGProperty; }
        set { txtRSSURL.BackColor = value; }
    }

    public Color TxtRSSURLFGProperty
    {
        get { return txtRSSURLFGProperty; }
        set { txtRSSURL.ForeColor = value; }
    }
}
```

And declare Form1:

```
public class Form1 : ThemeableForm { 
     // custom stuff for Form1, no need to write the common properties
}
```

I declared it as "internal" because you might want to control who/how THemeableForm is inherited.  But, you could make it public too.  And Settings can work with a ThemeableForm:

```
public Settings(ThemeableForm requestingForm)
{
    rssReaderMain = requestingForm as ThemeableForm;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private ThemeableForm rssReaderMain = null;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs args) {

    // Appearence settings for DEFAULT THEME

    if (cbThemeSelect.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        this.rssReaderMain.TxtRSSURLBGProperty = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
        this.rssReaderMain.TxtRSSURLFGProperty = Color.White;            
        [......about 25 more of these....]
    }
}
```

So you don't need to copy any of the Settings code for each and every other form type.

Comment: wow you are fast!  i cant wait to try this and get back to you.  thanks so much Jeff!  i'll give it a go

Comment: Okay Jeff, I tryed your code and now I get 'does not exist in the current context' for all of my controls.  I can make them public but I could always make them public and I've heard that is not a smart practice.  Here is a sample of my code for you to confirm:

Comment: Jeff, please see the code at the bottom of my original question that says 'Modified code for review' -- this is what I believe you said, and shows the error im getting.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Please also note that I am recieving a warning (details above) regarding the designer.

Comment: @Kurt - my abstract class solution assumes that anything that the Settings form can manipulate is actually declared and exists in ThemeableForm.  You changed the "set" to manipulate lRSS, which apparently is declared elsewhere.  I'll suggest two options: 1) You can move the controls' declarations to the ThemeableForm class, which fixes the "does not exist" issue and consolidates your control declarations, 2) A different approach: go back to setting Color variables in "set", then implement a Draw() function in Form1 to assign the property value to the control.